# Is there a way to view who viewed/accessed a file in linux?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, command

Hi I am a noob with linux server stuff.
I was wondering if there is a command in linux or there is a way to see which "user" has viewed or accessed a file in linux?

is there a such command?

I thought 'stat' command works could be a possible option, but after googling, I found out that someone posted here at the bottom:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/get-last-accessed-file-time-in-ubuntu-linux/
that there is not a way to view 'who' accessed a file. Is this true?

Comment: That information simply does not exist. Imagine how much overhead it would cause if even looking at a file caused a metadata append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audit subsystem can tell you who or what has accessed a filesystem object.

Comment: doesnt audit subsystem works if someone has modified a file? Does it work also for just viewing/accessing the file?

Comment: It can monitor any operation you tell it to.

Comment: oh I see thank you. Well is there a command to see if a specific server has a audit subsystem installed? For e.g., uname -a tells the version of linux server. I was wondering if there is a command like this for audit subsystem or other general subsystems.

Comment: Unfortunately no. All you can do is try to access it and see if it fails. Most of the big ones do have it though.

Comment: From what I found on google, it says it has to "# auditctl -w /etc/shadow -k shadow-file -p rwxa" do this command to watch a file. If I create a file do I have to do that command to watch a file, or does audit subsystem watches a new file automatically if it is in the kernel? I feel like I'm asking you too much questions about audit =(. Maybe I should just ask another question by making new post instead of just commenting... Well thank you for all your answers so far xD